# libmagic (file) database "use" and "clear" type

Tags: file-command

I am currently writing a parser for the libmagic database (used by the file command) and i don't found any information on the 'use' and 'clear' type (second column in the magic file).
Can someone explain to me what this types should do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are fairly new features, documented in [`magic(5)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=magic&sektion=5):

> **`use`**  
>   Recursively call the named magic starting from the
>   current offset.  If the name of the referenced
>   begins with a   **`^`** then the endianness of the magic is
>   switched; if the magic mentioned **`leshort`** for example, it is treated as    **`beshort`**   and vice versa.  This
>   is useful to avoid duplicating the rules for different endianness.
>
> **`clear`**
>    This test is always true and clears the match    flag
>   for that continuation   level.  It is intended to be
>   used with the   default test.

By "fairly new":

2014-11-27  18:40  Christos Zoulas

```
    * Allow setting more parameters from the command line.
    * Split name/use and indirect magic recursion limits.
```

2013-04-22  11:20  Christos Zoulas

```
    * The way "default" was implemented was not very useful
      because the "if something was printed at that level"
      was not easily controlled by the user, and the format
      was bound to a string which is too restrictive. Add
      a "clear" for that level keyword and make "default"
      void. This way one can do:            

            >>13    clear   x
            >>13    lelong  1       foo
            >>13    lelong  2       bar
            >>13    default x
            >>>13   lelong  x       unknown %x
```

Comment: I checked the source (was curious...), saw it was documented as quoted, and found an up-to-date copy.